# More links to other stackoverflow sub-domains

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

The links at the bottom of the page to other stackoverflow sites/domains is very nice. I would like to have links for more stackoverflow sites there.  Either having it customizable by the user or having it show all sites the user has shared login credentials would be equally good ways for me.

I know it sounds lazy, but sometimes I hit two or three pages til I get the advertisement on the right hand for starcraft so i can go to games.stackoverflow.com

This is an awesome site guys!  Thanks for all your great work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is coming, in the upper left hand corner. We have v0.5 up now.

Soon it will be:

http://a.imageshack.us/img826/1889/segenuwinebranding.png